# modify the subsequent values of a column in sql table which already contains data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello i am working on a project where i have to store some values in the database on click of a button. This is the code for creating the table:

```
create table dbo.Cpecial_Partner_Info_tbl
( 
[S.No] int identity(1,1),
[Partner ID] varchar(20),
[Partner Code] varchar(20),
[Partner Name] varchar(100),
[Partner Type] varchar(15),
[User ID] varchar(50) primary key,
[Password] varchar(50),
)
```

in this table i added some values. Now my requirement is that the **partner id** and **partner code** values should come from s.no values. For example, if my **s.no** value is '**1**', the **partnerid** and **parnter code** values should be '**part01**' and '**pc01**' resp. I know the code to create a fresh table and use my condition. This is the code i can use:

```
create table dbo.Cpecial_Partner_Info_tbl
( 
[S.No] int identity(1,1),
[Partner ID] as 'PART' + right('0' + Convert(VarChar(10), [S.No]), 1) persisted,
[Partner Code] as 'PC' + right('0' + Convert(VarChar(10), [S.No]), 1) persisted,
[Partner Name] varchar(100),
[Partner Type] varchar(15),
[User ID] varchar(50) primary key,
[Password] varchar(50),
)
```

but using the above code means i have to re-create the table. So  my question is can i apply the above condition for **partner id** and **partner code** without re-creating the table(as i already have some data in the table which is important) ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have to re-create the table? You can just remove two columns and create new ones with the definition you want (see [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.100).aspx)) without affecting the rest of the table. Or do you mean that you have existing values in the the PartnerID and PartnerCode columns that do not fit your formula, but you want to keep them anyway and only use the formula for new rows? And as a side note, using spaces in column names is usually a bad idea: it creates all sorts of 'small' problems with scripting and programming.

Comment: @Pondlife yes that is exactly what i want... even i am against using spaces in column names but my team is following a certain namespacing so i have to use that

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting the values to table take a max value of slno to a variable and set the variable to all the 3 columns.

Comment: actually i am inserting the values into the table through c#...so i think i need to create a stored procedure to insert the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in order to update your table and keep the data:
1. Create new table with same structure 
2. Copy data from old table to new table
3. Disable all foreign keys in old table
4. Update old table
5. Enable foreign keys again

Comment: is it not possible to do this without creating another table?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only way I know of. Sorry for the late reply.